Increasing Web Scraping speed with puppeteer
I am trying to create an Node.js API, that scrapes website, (I started only with Goodreads as a website to be scraped and will expand further when I first the optimize the approach) and provides the scraped data to the end user, which will be using my API.
My initial approach was planning the API structure, deciding to use puppeteer and then start creating. When creating the first endpoint successfully I noticed something - it tooks about 2-3 seconds in Postman, in order for the request to finish, which is really slow.
Here is my code:
scraper-handler.ts

import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
import { MOST_POPULAR_LISTS } from "../utils/api/urls-endpoints.js";
import { listScraper } from "./spec-scrapers/list-scraper.js";
import { lists } from "../utils/api/full-urls.js";
import puppeteer from "puppeteer";
import { GOODREADS_POPULAR_LISTS_URL } from "../utils/goodreads/urls.js";

export const scraperHandler = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    // headless: false,
    // defaultViewport: null,
  });

  const pages = await browser.pages();

  await pages[0].setUserAgent(
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36"
  );

  switch (req.url) {
    case `/${MOST_POPULAR_LISTS}`: {
      const result = await listScraper(
        browser,
        pages[0],
        GOODREADS_POPULAR_LISTS_URL,
        1,
        ".cell",
        ".listTitle",
        ".listTitle"
      );

      res.status(200).json({
        status: "success",
        data: result,
      });
      break;
    }
    default: {
      next();
      break;
    }
  }
};

And here is the case /${MOST_POPULAR_LISTS}:
list-scraper.ts

import puppeteer, { Page } from "puppeteer";
import { Browser } from "puppeteer";

export const listScraper = async (
  browser: Browser,
  page: Page,
  url: string,
  pageI = 1,
  main: string,
  title = "",
  ref = ""
)  => {
  // const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto(url, {
    waitUntil: "domcontentloaded",
  });
  
  const books = await page.evaluate(
    (mainSelector, titleSelector, refSelector) => {
      // const nextLink = document.querySelector('a[rel="next"]');

      // console.log(nextLink);
      const elements = document.querySelectorAll(mainSelector);
      
      return Array.from(elements)
        .slice(0, 3)
        .map((element) => {
          const title =
            titleSelector.length > 0 &&
            (element.querySelector(titleSelector) as HTMLElement | null)
              ?.innerText;
          const ref =
            refSelector.length > 0 &&
            (element.querySelector(refSelector) as HTMLAnchorElement | null)
              ?.href;

          return { title, ref };
        });
    },
    main,
    title,
    ref
  );
  // await page.click(".pagination > a");

  await browser.close();

  return books;
};


Here is the Goodreads url, from where I started:
export const GOODREADS_POPULAR_LISTS_URL = "https://www.goodreads.com/list/popular_lists";
So my question is how I can optimize my approach and what techniques can I use, in order to make the scraping faster and thus drastically improve the performance of my API?
I searched various posts and many suggest some kind of manipulation of the CPU, but I didn't understood how it could be used in my case. Also the Child process in Node.js was suggested quite few times.
Thank you in advance!

What's the URL? You might be able to disable JS, or use fetch rather than Puppeteer, or at least block resources like stylesheets, images, fonts, tracking scripts and so forth that aren't pertinent to the data you're extracting. You may also be able to bypass the site and hit an API directly, or at least intercept a network response. All of this is site-dependent.

Here it is: export const GOODREADS_POPULAR_LISTS_URL = "https://www.goodreads.com/list/popular_lists";

Thanks. I think the data is available statically so try just using fetch and cheerio rather than Puppeteer, or at least disable JS and block any requests you can. The caching tip in the answer seems good too--I doubt this data changes all that often, probably caching for an hour or at least half an hour would save a ton of work in most cases, or even running a background job hourly so you can serve the data instantly always.

I totally agree, I saw that it is static, and probably cheerio might be the answer for that, but puppeteer just seems more powerful, and is the go-to for dynamic websites, like SPA. Is a hybrid approach appropriate?

If it's static, then adding the overhead of puppeteer is moot. If it's not a spa, why use a tool that's used for spa? Why hybridize if it's not a spa?

I meant in the future, when I create scraping for more websites, a dynamic ones also.

I also discuss that in my blog post. There's almost no use case I can see for combining Puppeteer and fetch/Cheerio--if the data is there statically and the server lets you through, use the simpler fetch option. If the data can't be obtained with the simpler option, then you're forced to use a more complex approach like Puppeteer. Give it a read--I think it'll be worth your time and will basically answer all of your questions.

If potentially this API evolves into a scraping API at some point, how would the approach be - for static websites it would be cheerio + fetch and for dynamic ones - puppeteer?

Sure, but keep in mind there are no silver bullets in scraping, so it really depends on the sites you're scraping and the use case and the nature of the data you want to obtain. It's not quite as simple as a hard-and-fast rule, just rules of thumb. Your guidelines are good, but there are an infinite number of exceptions, so prepare for a lot of work if you're trying to write a general scraping API, unless you can accept some constraints, like a limited set of sites, only capturing simple responses, or accepting a fairly high failure rate. Hard to say much more without more details.

It is, I think, obvious that I am beginner in the scraping world, to say, so I am just trying to figure out how to do it and then will proceed on more complex tasks, like that more generic API we are talking about. But for example if I want to scrape books data from multiple websites and there are both static & SPA, how would that "generic API" look like in this example. Also what do you mean by saying "like a limited set of sites, only capturing simple responses, or accepting a fairly high failure rate."

Your approach seems like overkill to me. The data you want is in the static HTML, so a single request to the page looks like enough to get the data, using Node's built-in fetch API and a simple static HTML parser, Cheerio:
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // ^1.0.0-rc.12

const url = "<Your URL>";

fetch(url)
  .then(res => {
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw Error(res.statusText);
    }

    return res.text();
  })
  .then(html => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    const data = [...$(".listTitle")].map(e => ({
      title: $(e).text(),
      ref: $(e).attr("href"),
    }));
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

For sake of comparison, here's an optimized Puppeteer version:
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^22.6.0

const url = "<Your URL>";

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
  const ua =
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36";
  await page.setUserAgent(ua);
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.on("request", req => {
    if (req.url() === url) {
      req.continue();
    } else {
      req.abort();
    }
  });
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const data = await page.$$eval(".listTitle", els => els.map(el => ({
    title: el.textContent,
    ref: el.href,
  })));
  console.log(data);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());

Here's (basically) your version--unoptimized other than "domcontentloaded", which is a good start:
let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const ua =
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36";
  await page.setUserAgent(ua);
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const data = await page.$$eval(".listTitle", els => els.map(el => ({
    title: el.textContent,
    ref: el.href,
  })));
  console.log(data);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());

Unoptimized Puppeteer:
real 0m1.806s
user 0m0.801s
sys  0m0.204s

Optimized Puppeteer:
real 0m1.251s
user 0m0.651s
sys  0m0.107s

Fetch + Cheerio:
real 0m0.836s
user 0m0.251s
sys  0m0.035s

Using fetch and Cheerio is over a 2x speedup, with simpler code and no dependency on a complex library like Puppeteer. The main reasons to use Puppeteer for scraping are when you need to perform complex interactions like clicks, intercept requests, work with cookies, avoid blocks, wait for SPAs to load, etc (some of those cases may apply here, but first add a user agent to the fetch request if you're getting blocked).
Regardless of the scraping approach you take, caching the response is a good idea. I doubt the data changes that much, so you can re-fetch only ever hour or so, possibly in a background job, and serve it instantly to everyone from the cache via your proxy.
See this blog post of mine for details on the techniques I used to speed this script up.

cheerio is indeed blazingly fast. Thank you for your response

There's a few things that can be looked at to improve the speed of this.

The first major pain point I see is creating a new puppeteer instance on each request. We can create a module following the singleton pattern.

// browser_instance.ts
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

let browserInstance = null;

export async function getBrowser() {
    if (!browserInstance) {
        browserInstance = await puppeteer.launch({ ... });
    }
    return browserInstance;
}

Then in your code, attempt to get the instance
import { getBrowser } from './browser-instance.js';
....
export const scraperHandler = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const browser = await getBrowser();
    // ... use the browser instance for scraping
};


Consider using Promise.all to wait for all requests to finish in a concurrent manner.

const results = await Promise.all(listUrls.map(async (url) => {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    // ... scraping logic for each page ...
}));


A second approach would be to cache existing websites you've already hit if the data doesn't change much.

There are a lot more optimisations you can make. Consider researching how to find the slow points within your application and do some research on how to optimise the process.

Where should I use Promise.all? :)
